# How can I click on a popup window in selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]I am new to selenium and try to automate (using selenium Webdriver in Java for Window and using Chrome Driver) an App (ABC Project) which contains a Registration Form.

After completing the form and click on Registration Button I get a popup info message (modal) with close (X) & OK Button & Headline in the message: Under ABC Project the following is displayed & Text which informs the user that the registration was successful.

I have tried several ways to click on OK button in this popup window but no success:

```
1. 

    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                   alert.accept();

 2. 

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'alert']")).click();
               Alert javascriptAlert = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();
               System.out.println(javascriptAlert.getText()); // Get text on alert box
               javascriptAlert.accept();
               ----> in this case I get only the text of the opened tab (from registration window: driver.getTitle();:ABC Project) but not the text of teh Info message(to see in logger.info) 

 3. 

    String winHandleBefore =   
        driver.getWindowHandle();
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-4']/button[1]")).click();
        // Xpath of register Button
               Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles();    ..... --->>, In this case, I don't get any Window Handler of new window the window handler from old and new are the same
```

**Additional Hint:**

- I am also not able to click anywhere else in Window to skip the popup window
- In Google Developer tool I don't see also any source code and no Elements from the popup window (when the popups appear.
- I heard from developer that this window is a javascript but I don't
  see anything in source code too (it did not also work with solution b
  above)

I appreciate for any tips and supports
Thanks

Comment: can you post a picture of the alert ?

Comment: I have already added the picture of dialog - thx for reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This picture posted looks like a javascript alert.

So the below code should have worked.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Maybe it is a wait issue. Try WebDriverWait

```
Alert alert = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
alert.accept();
```